# Why instance initiazer block in java executed only once?

Tags: java

```
class B {

    {
        System.out.println("IIB B");
    }

    B(int i) {
        System.out.println("Cons B int");

    }

    public B() {
        this(10);
        System.out.println("Cons B");
    }
}

public class C extends B {

    {
        System.out.println("IIB C");
    }

    public C() {
        System.out.println("Cons C");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c1 = new C();
    }
}
```

---

Output

```
 IIB B
Cons B int
Cons B
 IIB C
Cons C
```

As per [Oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) ,

> "The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor.
>   Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between
>   multiple constructors."

So why initializer blocks of class B is not executed twice as constructor is executing twice?

Comment: then how many times you want it to be executed? initialization process  executes only once in any creation process in universe.

Comment: See http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076614/core-java/object-initialization-in-java.html for a more detailed overview of object initialisation in Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So why initializer blocks of class B is not executed twice as constructor is executing twice?

No, the constructor runs only once. Delegating work to another constructor is taken into account by the compiler and the instance initializers are not copied into a constructor which begins with a `this()` invocation.

In general, you don't need to bother reasoning about where exactly the instance initializer code is copied. Simply rely on the fact that it will run *once and only once* for each object initialization.

The moment at which instance initializers run is immediately after completing the `super()` constructor call.

---

#### A terminological note

The link you include in your question is not the Javadocs, but an Oracle Tutorial. There is a very important difference between these two: Javadocs are *normative* whereas the tutorials are only *descriptive*. Some wording in the tutorials may be imprecise as a compromise between teaching value and factual accuracy.

If you ever have a doubt about something you have read in a tutorial, then try to find the authoritative statement in the Java Language Specification or the JDK Javadoc.

Comment: So the statement "The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor." is false???

Answer (score 4):

You have created only one instance of `B`.i.e. an instance of `C`. so, it will get printed only once since the constructor runs only once. Try creating another instance of `C`, then you will get it printed twice.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Initializer {
    {
        System.out.println("in initializer");
    }

    public Initializer() {
        this(false);
        System.out.println("in no-arg constructor");
    }

    public Initializer(boolean b) {
        System.out.println("in boolean constructor");
    }
}
```

Here's the bytecode generated for the above class:

```
public class com.foo.Initializer {
  public com.foo.Initializer();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: iconst_0      
       2: invokespecial #1                  // Method "<init>":(Z)V
       5: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       8: ldc           #3                  // String in no-arg constructor
      10: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      13: return        

  public com.foo.Initializer(boolean);
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #5                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       7: ldc           #6                  // String in initializer
       9: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      12: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      15: ldc           #7                  // String in boolean constructor
      17: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      20: return        
}
```

You see that the initializer block is not actually copied to all the constructors. It's copied only in the boolean constructor, because the compiler detects that the no-arg constructor delegates to the boolean constructor. The sentence in the tutorial is thus a simplification of what actually happens.

Comment: could you add a link to the specification about this?